# Bash script to print X lines of a file in sequence

Tags: bash, loops, awk

I'd be very grateful for your help with something probably quite simple.

I have a table (table2.txt), which has a single column of randomly generated numbers, and is about a million lines long.

```
2655087
3721239
5728533
9082076
2016819
8983893
9446748
6607974
```

I want to create a loop that repeats 10,000 times, so that for iteration 1, I print lines 1 to 4 to a file (file0.txt), for iteration 2, I print lines 5 to 8 (file1.txt), and so on.

What I have so far is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..10000}
do
awk 'NR==((4 * "$i") +1)' table2.txt > file"$i".txt
awk 'NR==((4 * "$i") +2)' table2.txt >> file"$i".txt
awk 'NR==((4 * "$i") +3)' table2.txt >> file"$i".txt
awk 'NR==((4 * "$i") +4)' table2.txt >> file"$i".txt
done
```

Desired output for file0.txt:

```
2655087
3721239
5728533
9082076
```

Desired output for file1.txt:

```
2016819
8983893
9446748
6607974
```

Something is going wrong with this, because I am getting identical outputs from all my files (i.e. they all look like the desired output of file0.txt). Hopefully you can see from my script that during the second iteration, i.e. when i=2, I want the output to be the values of rows 5, 6, 7 and 8.

This is probably a very simple syntax error, and I would be grateful if you can tell me where I'm going wrong (or give me a less cumbersome solution!)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

The beauty of `awk` is that you can do this in one `awk` line :

```
awk '{ print > ("file"c".txt") }
     (NR % 4 == 0) { ++c }
     (c == 10001) { exit }' <file>
```

This can be slightly more optimized and file handling friendly (cfr. [James Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49898849/8344060)):

```
awk 'BEGIN{f="file0.txt" }
     { print > f }
     (NR % 4 == 0) { close(f); f="file"++c".txt" }
     (c == 10001) { exit }' <file>
```

*Why did your script fail?*

The reason why your script is failing is because you used single quotes and tried to pass a shell variable to it. Your lines should read :

```
awk 'NR==((4 * '$i') +1)' table2.txt > file"$i".txt
```

but this is very ugly and should be improved with

```
awk -v i=$i 'NR==(4*i+1)' table2.txt > file"$i".txt
```

*Why is your script slow?*

The way you are processing your file is by doing a loop of 10001 iterations. Per iterations, you perform 4 `awk` calls. Each `awk` call reads the full file completely and writes out a single line. So in the end you read your files 40004 times.

To optimise your script step by step, I would do the following :

1. Terminate `awk` to step reading the file after the line is print

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   for i in {0..10000}; do
     awk -v i=$i 'NR==(4*i+1){print; exit}' table2.txt > file"$i".txt
     awk -v i=$i 'NR==(4*i+2){print; exit}' table2.txt >> file"$i".txt
     awk -v i=$i 'NR==(4*i+3){print; exit}' table2.txt >> file"$i".txt
     awk -v i=$i 'NR==(4*i+4){print; exit}' table2.txt >> file"$i".txt
   done
   ```
2. Merge the 4 `awk` calls into a single one. This prevents reading the first lines over and over per loop cycle.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   for i in {0..10000}; do
     awk -v i=$i '(NR<=4*i)    {next}            # skip line
                  (NR> 4*(i+1)}{exit}            # exit awk
                  1' table2.txt > file"$i".txt  # print line
   done
   ```
3. remove the final loop (see top of this answer)

Comment: Thank you! That is very elegant! Two questions though: 
1. Is it possible to get the file output to be "file1.txt", "file2.txt", rather than "file00001.txt", "file00002.txt"? 
2. Secondly, does this automatically stop at 10,000 iterations? 
Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

With just bash you can do it very simple:

```
chunk=4
files=10000
head -n $(($chunk*$files)) table2.txt |
  split -d -a 5 --additional-suffix=.txt -l $chunk - file
```

Basically read first 10k lines and split them into chunks of 4 consecutive lines, using `file` as prefix and `.txt` as suffix for the new files.

If you want a numeric identifier, you will need 5 digits (`-a 5`), as pointed in the comments (credit: @kvantour).

Comment: Be aware it is `head -n 40004 table2.txt`

Comment: Edited. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the math part be `$(($chunk*$files))` instead of `$($chunk*$files)`? You also don't need a backslash at the end of the line after the pipe (`|`). I admire the enthusiasm with which you said it can be "very simple" though :-).

Comment: I agree @EdMorton that the options make it a bit complex. With simplicity I mean that it does not require loops with modulo operations at all, just two commands connected with a pipe (quite common in bash). I've corrected the `$(( ))`. The backslash is to avoid the code block to insert a scrollbar.

Comment: I just found it funny to say it's simple but then have multiple corrections :-). You can remove the backslash, there won't be a scrollbar.

Answer (score 3):

This is functionally the same as [@JamesBrown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49898849/1745001) but just written more awk-ishly so don't accept this, I just posted it to show the more idiomatic awk syntax as you can't put formatted code in a comment.

```
awk '
    (NR%4)==1 { close(out); out="file" c++ ".txt" }
    c > 10000 { exit }
    { print > out }
' file
```

See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some of the reasons why you should avoid shell loops for manipulating text.

Answer (score 2):

Another awk:

```
$ awk '{if(NR%4==1){if(i==10000)exit;close(f);f="file" i++ ".txt"}print > f}' file
$ ls 
file file0.txt  file1.txt
```

Explained:

```
awk ' {
    if(NR%4==1) {            # use mod to recognize first record of group
        if(i==10000)         # exit after 10000 files 
            exit             # test with 1
        close(f)             # close previous file
        f="file" i++ ".txt"  # make a new filename
    }
    print > f                # output record to file
}' file
```